# SMS read receipt through website

Tags: sms

I am php developer and for our project (mobile website developed using JQM) we need following functionality,
We need to send SMS to the customer and when customer reads the SMS we need to get the receipt in our site so we can store in database.
I have checked different SMS service api such as ,
Nexmo,plivo,tropo,Twilio,textlocal,clockworksms
Most of them providing facility of the Delivery Receipts such as "delivered/undelivered/QUEUED/ACCEPTD" which denotes delivery status but we want weather SMS is read.
Is this possible in mobile website?
I have checked some reference which gives idea about doing it with andriod app.
http://mobiforge.com/design-development/sms-messaging-android

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have worked with several of the SMS gateway APIs you mention and talked to a number of SMS service providers over 2+ years. The answer to your questions is: No, there is no such thing as a read receipt for SMS in general -- to the very best of my knowledge.

The API delivery status is all you get. And even that status is not 100% reliable. Text messages usually go over a number of hubs to reach their target and service quality and response reliability depend on these.

If you want to make sure the user received your message, you need to have them respond either on you website (with some code you supplied) or by responding to your SMS (in which case you would have to send your message from your own inbound number).

You can get a more definite answer when you do payments via SMS. In this case, there will be multi-step protocols involved that ensure completion of the entire messaging process.

Comment: +1 - this agrees with my experience. The basic SMS protocol simply doesn't support a proper "read receipt", and the "delivery status" is unreliable.